# Trigger after update to update linked server table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

Basically I have an app where upon column field change (update) another table on a linked server gets updated.

After modifying reference number through an app, this value gets updated in **Table_A**.
Now I wan't to trigger update of **Table_B** if **Table_A** column field reference number is updated.( **only check for update of this very field** )

```
USE [SRV1]

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[BenRef_UPDATE]
 ON [dbo].[Table_A]
  AFTER UPDATE
    AS

 BEGIN
     SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF UPDATE(refNum) 

    UPDATE [EXPSRV1].[OPR].[protected].[TransferServiceArrangement] 
    SET PaymentDetailsBeneficiaryReferenceNumber = i.refNum
    FROM inserted i
       INNER JOIN deleted d 
              ON d.party= i.party 

  END;
```

Right now I am unable to update Table_A when Trigger is created, no change will occur, when I drop the trigger and modify number the change reflects on the Table_A.

What did I miss ?

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to attempt to access *external resources* (anything outside of your own DB) from a trigger. Do you really want, say, an intermittent network fault to *prevent* the original `update` to `table_A` from succeeding? Usually better to *queue* the work the trigger wants done (table used as a queue, service broker, etc) and have some *separate* activity deal with those possible problems.

Comment: I would really appreciate an example based on the one I provided, so I can explore the topic further while implementing it.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: He means creating a table Delayed_Payments, where you save the Party and RefNum after every update. Then you write an small application that reads that table, updates the external server and removes the entry.